# Whats going to happen with COleTemplateServer::RegisterAll() in windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, registry, uac, elevated-privileges

Ok, so we have a C++ app that runs fine in Windows XP.
It has the following code in the initialization

```
// Register all OLE server (factories) as running.  This enables the
//  OLE libraries to create objects from other applications.
COleObjectFactory::RegisterAll();
```

Now like i said, it works fine in Windows XP, but as far I understand the program tries to register its COM interface Which is fine in XP, but this may be a problem in Windows Vista and Windows 7 because of the UAC.  Especially if its is run as a standard user (with no elevated privileges).

If i understand it correctly this is needed for the program to run properly, but it cant execute this code without elevated privileges. If it will run every time the app runs (this usually runs when `CWinApp::init()` is run)

**Before you say just use admin privileges**, the user will not have them, there is no way to change that

So, now my questions are:

1) am i correct in my assumptions?

2) if I am correct, what is the best way around this? Can i just remove this? Do i need to set up some other thing? (we changed some VB modules to use a XML file instead of stuff in the registry

PS: the modules compiles into DLLs

PPS: UAC MUST be on

Comment: Why don't you just try this out under windows 7?

Comment: Who says it needs administrator privileges? If it's registering itself as the class factory without touching the registry then it shouldn't need admin. If it registers itself into HKCU then it shouldn't need admin. I don't know the specifics but it sounds like it calls http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693407(v=vs.85).aspx which has no mention of privilege requirements.

Comment: @RedX - im trying to set up a W7 machine now. but i can only do W7 32bit, but there are those virtualization things between 32bit and 64bit that might be a problem?

Comment: @ta.speot.is  - this would be awesome if it is right, I read about the registering and assumed that it would have to do with the registry(which needs elevated privileges)

Comment: Applications can write to HKCU just fine, no elevation necessary.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, sorry, i made a mistake with the exact piece of code(look edit). is the same still valid?

Comment: I went off the comments, not the function name.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, how can i confirm that this is infact the case? cause ive been looking and cant find anything official. maybe its my google kung fu thats week, but like i said, i am not finding anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note that:

1. The documentation for these functions makes no mention of any privilege requirements; and
2. nobody online seems to be having trouble with these functions in limited privilege environments; and
3. it's 2012, I think someone would have noticed if these functions didn't work under UAC by now.

So (with nothing to suggest otherwise) I'd say It Just Works.

Notwithstanding the above, I looked at the implementation of `COleObjectFactory::RegisterAll()` and `COleObjectFactory::UpdateRegistryAll()`.

## `RegisterAll`

Ultimately calling `RegisterAll` ends up in `olefact.cpp:135` where  `CoRegisterClassObject` is called. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693407.aspx):

> Registers an EXE class object with OLE so other applications can connect to it.

I believe this registration will be limited to the current user's session and the lifetime of the application. The **Remarks** section touches on privileges (*As of Windows Server 2003...*) but doesn't provide anything concrete.

There's an object known as the `Running Object Table` (ROT) that can be retrieved via [`GetRunningObjectTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684004.aspx). The documentation has this snippet:

> Each workstation has a local ROT that maintains a table of the objects that have been registered as running on that computer.

[The COM Elevation Moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx) has some more information about the ROT and privileges (it suggests processes of various privilege levels work fine with it). The links on the left-hand side might help, too.

Overall it seems there's nothing to suggest that `CoRegisterClassObject` requires administrator permissions.

## `UpdateRegistryAll`

This function ends up in `olefact.cpp:375` where it opens `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. At this point [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx) gets a bit better:

> Registry functions such as `RegOpenKeyEx` or `RegQueryValueEx` allow you to specify the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key. When you call these functions from a process running in the interactive user account, the system merges the default settings in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` with the interactive user's settings at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.

Further on:

> If you write keys to a key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, the system stores the information under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`

The documentation doesn't define what happens when you try to write to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` under limited privileges (i.e. a standard user can't write to `HKLM`), but I *believe* that you'll end up writing to `HKCU` instead.

And finally, note:

> **Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP/2000**:  Applications can register dependent COM objects to either the per-machine or per-user COM configuration store (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`).

So if it falls through to `HKCU`, you should be fine.

**Caveat Implementor**: Don't rely on implementation details.